# search string query with pattern

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table as below

table1

```
id type

1   Aches, Pain, Fever
2   Fever
3   Fever Blisters
4   Hay Fever
5   Typhoid Fever
6   Valley Fever
7   Viral Hemorrhagic Fever
8   Yellow Fever
9   Fever with chills
10  Fever well
11  Day fever
12  Fever from week
13  Dengue Fever
14  Fever with cold
15  Fever with chills One
16  Fever hi
17  high grade fever
```

table2

```
id type

1   Acute Valley Fever
2   Allergic Rhinitis (Hay Fever)
3   Breakbone Fever 
4   Coccidioidomycosis (Valley Fever)
5   Typhoid2 Fever
6   Valleyrt Fever
```

I am trying this with php codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("id,type");
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->like('type', $searchterm, 'after');
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select("id,type");
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->like('type', $searchterm, 'both');
$this->db->not_like('type', $searchterm, 'after');
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$searchResult = $this->db->query($query1 . " UNION " . $query2)->result();

if (sizeof($searchResult) > 0) {
    return $searchResult;
} else {
    return [];
}
```

I want to show a list of type on search with keyword 'fever'.
I want output from table1 and table2 as below

1. firstly show types which start with keyword 'fever'
2. then show types which contains keyword 'fever' as a substring

What can i do to fetch records from another table?

Comment: What problem you are facing? You have already did code to achieve what you want

Comment: @RahulMeshram i forgot to add about second table

Comment: And what is the role of `table2`?

Comment: i am searching with keyword fever and want to show records from both table but as mentioned  above

Comment: So you are saying $tblname will be `table1` in first query and `table2` in second query right?

Comment: i tried this only on table1 it works perfectly with search pattern. i also tried join query with table 2 it gives all records but not in pattern which i want

Comment: `$query1` will be related to `table1` and `$query2` related to `table2` can I consider this?

Comment: no..both queries i tried for table1

Comment: Join query with table 2 will not work because on what basis you are going to join as you don't have PK and FK set on both tables. Those tables are not related to each other using keys.

Comment: Also I can't understand why there are 2 tables as same structure. As type values are may be going to same in those 2 tables.